# Issue with double quotes and fread function

Tags: r, data.table

I have some column entries that look like this:

```
c("This is just a "shame"...") # since its a character
```

THIS WILL WRITE A FILE ON YOUR C:\ DRIVE:

```
sample.data <- data.frame(case1=c("This is just a 'shame'..."), 
                          case2="This is just a shame") # here I could not make it to insert the double quotes 
write.csv(sample.data, file="C:/sample_data.csv")

require(data.table)
test.fread <- fread("C:/sample_data.csv")
test.read.csv <- read.csv("C:/sample_data.csv")
```

If I read the `csv` data with `fread` function (from data.table), I get his error:

```
Bumped column 79 to type character on data row 12681, field contains '   
a.n."'. Coercing previously read values in this column from logical, 
integer or numeric back to character which may not be lossless; e.g., if 
'00' and '000' occurred before they will now be just '0', and there 
may be inconsistencies with treatment of ',,' and ',NA,' too (if they 
occurred in this column before the bump). If this matters please rerun 
and set 'colClasses' to 'character' for this column. Please note that column
type detection uses the first 5 rows, the middle 5 rows and the 
last 5 rows, so hopefully this message should be very rare. 
If reporting to datatable-help, please rerun and include 
the output from verbose=TRUE.
```

If I use `read.csv` no error occurs and the entries are read in correctly!

Question 1: How can I remove the double quotes inside the `character` name.

Question 2: Why read.csv reads the entries correctly but `fread` fails?

Comment: thanks, but I have random names and multiple entries in data I'm reading in, so cannot just escape the entry.

Comment: In general in R `"` to quote single quote and vice versa.

Comment: See perhaps [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1109)

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, it seems that it explains it all. I have to check with my data though.

Comment: Have you tried with the current devel [v1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)?

Comment: No, I have got:  data.table_1.9.4 loaded. I will try, thanks.

Comment: Would be great if you could try it, and write back. Installation instructions can be found in the project wiki. If it works, you can go ahead and answer it yourself..

Comment: Yes, I will definitely write back, soonest however tomorrow. Hope that's okay. Thanks.

Comment: @Arun: Thank you, Indeed the devel version 1.9.5 solved the issue! This is great. I'm not sure what to do now with this question, what do you think? Close it or leave it open?

Comment: @Maximilian, you can answer it yourself and accept it, so that it's useful for others who might come across the issue.. (until 1.9.5 is pushed to CRAN as 1.9.6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Arun kindly suggested, the `data.table` development version 1.9.5 currently on github may be of help here.

To install please follow this procedure (Rtools required):

```
# To install development version

library(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

It has been tested so this is to confirm that the newest version of `data.table` solves the issue with double quotes without problems.

For further details and updates check the following link [github data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)