# Issues in Reading quotes using fread

Tags: r, csv, data.table, double-quotes

I am trying to read around 100 csv files, each containing 200,000 rows. So I was comparing fread vs read.csv, and fread is indeed much faster. However, it reads some records incorrectly.

few lines of a csv file:

```
ID,raw_title,semi_clean,semi_clean_id
1,0 - 0,,0
2,"""0 - 1,000,000""",,0
27448,"20yr. rope walker
igger",Rope Walker Igger,1832700817
```

Here is my code and the output.

```
x = read.csv("file1.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
y = fread("file1.csv")

x
  ï..ID                raw_title        semi_clean semi_clean_id
1     1                    0 - 0                               0
2     2          "0 - 1,000,000"                               0
3 27448 20yr. rope walker\nigger Rope Walker Igger    1832700817

y
   ï»¿ID                raw_title        semi_clean semi_clean_id
1:     1                    0 - 0                               0
2:     2        ""0 - 1,000,000""                               0
3: 27448 20yr. rope walker\rigger Rope Walker Igger    1832700817
```

Check the raw_title in row 2. The correct value for me is "0 - 1,000,000".
Also, just out of curiosity, name of first column (ID) gets some strange additional characters.

R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
data.table version 1.9.6 (Earlier I was using data table 1.9.1, and it was throwing an error while reading last line of this sample file, so I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478316/issue-with-double-quotes-and-fread-function) and updated my data table to current CRAN version)

Comment: Did you try `readr::read_csv()`?

Comment: No, I have not, I just read the documentation of readr, and it seems pretty general and fast. Thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: Also, those "extra" characters for the `ID` field indicate you're probably on Windows and that's probably a file with a byte-order mark (BOM) in it.

Comment: That's because it is `read_csv`